# Chart.js v2.0 - colouring individual bars differently

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've just moved over to chart.js v2.0 from v1 but after several hours of searching I can't figure out how to change the colour of an individual bar (or set of bars) in my bar graph.
From an answer on here - the following code would achieve what I want in version 1.0

```
// Change 2nd bar to red (display).
wpChartChartTitleBar.datasets[0].bars[1].fillColor = "rgba(229,12,12,0.7)";
wpChartChartTitleBar.datasets[0].bars[1].strokeColor = "rgba(229,12,12,1)";
```

but what's the equivalent in v2.0?
... or should I just revert to v1.0? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it by passing in an array for the `backgroundColor` property

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Script**

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["R", "B", "G", "Y"],
            datasets: [{
                    label: 'value',
                    data: [12, 19, 1, 14],
                    backgroundColor: ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"],
            }]
        }
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Lbap3L37/

Comment: You star! One of those things that's obvious once you know it. That works post-creation too  <Chartname>.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = ["red", "blue", etc ];

Comment: Cheers! Glad it worked out. Just check out one thing though (in your version of Chart.js) - if I set the 3rd value to 10, it doesn't show up. It appears to be a library bug, but I wasn't sure if it was because of the library file I linked to. Note - it doesn't have anything to do with the colors btw - it happens even without the barwise coloring.

Comment: I think that's because the y-axis is changing it's limits from [0->20] to [10->20] so your value of 10 is right on the bottom edge. You can force the y-axis to start from zero, but (for me at least) that's not usually helpful. I work around it by having thick borders on the bars, then the thick top border shows up over the x-axis.

Comment: Ah! I didn't even notice that the y-axis had changed and mistakenly assumed that it was an issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the myChart in this manner,(chartjs v2.0)

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
```

you have to change line color by this code

```
  myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0] ="#87CEFA";
```

---

If you initialize the myChart in this manner,(chartjs v1.0)

```
myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(barChartData, {
```

you have to change line color by this code

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =  "#FF0000";
```